# How to overide an inline style

Tags: css

this is my style

```
<section id="text-13" class="widget widget_text">
    <div class="widget-wrap">           
        <div class="textwidget">
            <div style="background-color:#f7f6f6; padding: 15px;">
                <div align="center">
                    <h2>Junte-se a mais de 4.137 assinantes:</h2>
                </div>
```

how can I override the div style = background through CSS without editing the file.

Comment: <section id="text-13" clas="widget widget_text">
>div class="widget-wrap">
<div class ="text widget">
<div style ="background-color:#f7f6f6;">

Comment: <section id="text-13" clas="widget widget_text">
>div class="widget-wrap">
<div class ="text widget">
<div style ="background-color:#f7f6f6;">

Comment: What is that coding for? its invalid by the way: `>div class="widget-wrap">`

Answer (score 2):

According to this [CSS Tricks Article](http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/):

```
.textwidget div[style] {
   background: yellow !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use !important

.textwidget > div {background: none!important}